# Unable to add Guava to NetBeans libraries

Tags: netbeans, guava

I'm trying to add [the Guava 18 release](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar) to a NetBeans project. I'm downloading it from their [GitHub](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release18) page.

But whenever I navigate in NetBeans, "Project" (right-click)  -> "Properties" -> "Libraries" -> "Add JAR/Folder", I'm unable to add the Guava  JAR that I downloaded.

This is strange, since I have no problem adding the Apache Commons Math JAR that I downloaded (and stored in the same folder).

Can anyone reproduce this problem, by creating a new NetBeans Project (in NetBeans 8.0.2), and trying to add the Guava JAR under Libraries?

Comment: I just downloaded the jar from your link and added it to a project with no apparent problems. Did you get an error message? Maybe the download was corrupted/incomplete. Try jar -tf the file to see if it looks ok.

Comment: I tried jar -tf and it looks okay. I'm using NetBeans 8.0.2 on OS X. I'm thinking this is a NetBeans bug? ... When I add the JAR, it simply doesn't show in the list. Nothing happens. When I add an Apache commons JAR, on the other hand, it shows up and adds successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Random things to try:

- Close netbeans, delete the cache directory (http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir),  and try again.
- Check messages.log for clues. (http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqLogMessagesFile)
- Check nbproject/project.properties

It should have something like:

```
file.reference.guava-18.0.jar=/home/shackle/Downloads/guava-18.0.jar
includes=**
jar.compress=false
javac.classpath=\
    ${file.reference.guava-18.0.jar}
```

You could try adding it manually if you have to.

- Import something from guava, if you can still compile maybe it is just a display bug.
- Create a Maven project instead, copy over your source, right-click dependencies, and add a dependency. You will need this info:

  groupId = com.google.guava
  artifactId=guava
  version=18.0

Comment: I see, thanks. I ended up checking the box which said "Use dedicated folder for libraries" and that worked. But I feel like I shouldn't have to do this. Maybe I'll look into it more sometime later.